# Is CompletableFuture run on different cores?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

When one uses CompletableFuture with Executor. Are these tasks run on different cores. Or it could it be the same core but just Threads from Theadpool? In the documentation I can't read anything about it . This task will be run in a for loop creating 10 tasks. Will these run on different cores . How can I check this ? Thanks

```
Executor testExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
CompletableFuture<String> name = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Baeldung",testExecutor);
```

Comment: It depends on your hardware. It is not guaranteed to run on different cores, but it most probably will.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, threads usually run on separate cores. Note that you can still only have one thread active per core (with minor exceptions for [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)), so if you're doing heavy CPU processing you shouldn't create more threads than your number of cores.

There's also some overhead switching between threads, so avoid creating too many threads even if they're IO bound. The thread pool you're using is a good way to manage that.

You are probably not finding many resources on this because thread management is a responsibility of the operating system, and not the language runtime.

I'm not aware of any easy way to check which core a thread is using, but you can always use your task manager to check how your process is distributed.

Comment: Your answer starts with the word yes, and than you pretty much describe a no.

Comment: @Sören I don't see the "no". Threads can freely run on separate cores. The rest of the answer is how to pick a number of threads for your pool.

Comment: You have to read "Are these tasks run on different cores" as "Are these tasks *guaranteed* to run on different cores". Otherwise, "Or [...] could it be the same core" wouldn't be a contradiction.

Comment: @Sören That's up to the operating system, per third paragraph.

Comment: "Usually run on separate cores" is pretty much inaccurate. If you have a quad-core system and a thread pool of 5 threads, then 2 threads are already on the same core, so not running on separate cores. Furthermore, the OS could pretty much schedule them on the same core, if there are other processes (possibly also multi-threaded) running on separate cores and taking a lot of the CPU cycles. Not to mention the background threads used by the JVM such as the garbage collector.

Comment: The question is about scheduling CompleteableFutures, but this answer never mentions CompletableFutures once. It only states that threads run on cores, but not how CompletableFutures are assigned threads and how JVM threads map to OS threads (they can all map to the same OS thread, especially since Virtual Threads have been introduced).

Comment: CompleteableFuture also run on different cores I hope. But not sure. We are just on Java 17.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the size of the thread pool, how many other threads you have running, how many other processes are competing for resources on the same machine, and how many CPU cores (or hyperthreading virtual cores) you have. There is no guarantee that they will be on different cores. Thread scheduling is controlled by the OS kernel, which usually switches context at strategic points, such as blocking I/O calls, or when where it deems some CPU cycles should be dedicated to a waiting thread.

As a side-note, from Java 21 onwards, you now also have virtual threads, which are handled by the JVM, and the OS would not even be aware of them. Multiple virtual threads would still run on one or more platform threads which the OS would schedule and parallelize (potentially on multiple cores), but the virtual threads themselves would be scheduled by the JVM.

Comment: It’s not accurate to say that virtual threads are “handled completely by the JVM”. They run atop a pool of platform threads which are again subject to the scheduling strategy of the underlying operating system.

Comment: Well obviously they need to run on some platform thread, duh, but the OS doesn't know about how many of them there are or decide how to schedule and parallelize their execution.

Comment: Since virtual threads run atop a *pool* of platform threads whose scheduling *is* controlled by the operating system, the operating system still has significant impact on the parallel processing capabilities. Most notably, whether virtual threads will utilize multiple cores or not, depends on whether the operating system distributes the platform threads over multiple cores or not.

Comment: Not exactly. The decision on how to map virtual threads to platform threads is up to the JVM and is an implementation detail that is specific to the JVM. The OS only schedules between the platform threads, it does not know that a specific platform thread is actually running multiple virtual threads. If the JVM decides to use multiple platform threads, then they are scheduled and potentially parallelized on multiple cores depending on the OS. But that has nothing to do with how virtual threads are yielding control between each other.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the statement which @Holger highlighted in his first comment. With that correction and the new addition in this edit, your answer makes complete sense to me.

Comment: @jbx I never was discussing “how virtual threads are yielding control between each other”. I only addressed your phrase “which are handled *completely* by the JVM”. Your revised answer is great (and should get the green checkmark).

Comment: @Holger got it... i guess we were referring to different perspectives of the same thing.